# Add appExecutionAlias manually?

Tags: windows-10, alias

By default, Windows 10 stores app-aliases in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` however this is only partially true (or not true at all, if you think about it). Listing the files in the directory indicates that alias is a soft symlink:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        05.01.2021     01:45                Backup
-a---l        05.01.2021     01:45              0 ubuntu2004.exe
```

That is also not true, because soft symlinks (at least the ones made with `mklink`) do not inherit `execution directory` from the target and you cant specify it for symlink in any way. You can for Windows Shortcut but it is a completely different semantic and underlying mechanism, renaming `MyAlias.exe.lnk` into `MyAlias.exe` is not gonna nest you desired results.

So apparently, Windows10 does way more behind the scenes to make such simple thing as app-alias work. Any idea what that can be?

Comment: Just an FYI, you can specify C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local by using %LocalAppData% environment variable. And %AppData% without LOCAL points to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming.